# How to reorder column names in R numerically?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-science

I'm turning some long-form data into wide-form. When I transform my rows to columns, they appear in the order 1, 10, 100 rather than 1,2,3, etc. How do I fix this? I have 100s of rows so I'd rather not manually type out the order.

I know this is an issue with the column names being strings and I attempted to simply use select(), however, this removes my cluster column. I also have tried the standard way of renaming my columns `(data <- data[c("A", "B", "C")])`.

I've also taken a look at the following threads and can't seem to parse it out. 
[Reordering columns in a large dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18339370/reordering-columns-in-a-large-dataframe)
[Preserve order of columns when going from wide to long format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46981189/preserve-order-of-columns-when-going-from-wide-to-long-format)
[R: Reorder columns from dcast output numerically instead of lexicographically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27412741/r-reorder-columns-from-dcast-output-numerically-instead-of-lexicographically)

Here is my code:

```
library(reshape2)
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyr)
library(gtools)
library(stringr)

rf_83_88 <- read.csv('Google Drive File Stream/My Drive/Bang_RIA/bang_83_05_rainfall_avg/Bangladesh-precipitation-decadal-83-88.csv')


groupdata_1 <- dcast(setDT(rf_83_88), cluster ~
                     paste0("precipitation", rowid(cluster)), value.var = "precipitation")
```

Here is the df sample it produces:

```
cluster        precipitation1  precipitation10 precipitation100
Akhai Bari _ 1   0               11.730278        11.12267
Akhai Bari _ 2   0               10.130148        12.53500
```

When I try:

```
test_select <- select(groupdata_1, num_range("precipitation", 0:nrow(groupdata_1))
```

, the df becomes ordered, however it drops cluster.

I'm relatively new to R (and stack) and tried reading the documentation to no avail. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `DF[,-1] <- DF[,-1][, order(as.numeric(gsub("precipitation", "", names(DF[, -1]))))]`?

Comment: I am getting this error when I try your solution ``` Error in `[<-.data.table`(`*tmp*`, , -1, value = c(1L, 112L, 144L, 155L,  : 
  Item 1 of column numbers in j is -1 which is outside range [1,ncol=221]. Use column names instead in j to add new columns.``` I tried replacing ```-1``` with ```"cluster"``` and get this message: ```Warning message:
In order(as.numeric(gsub("precipitation", "", names(groupdata_1[,  :
  NAs introduced by coercion ``` but there is no change in column order

Comment: Well, you didn't say you have a data.table. I'd assumed you have a regular data.frame. Maybe `setcolorder(DT, c(1, order(as.numeric(gsub("precipitation", "", names(DT)[-1]))) + 1))`.

Answer (score 1):

OP has clarified in comments that they actually have a data.table and not a regular data.frame.

1. Extract the column names and remove the first column name:

   `names(DT)[-1]`
2. Extract the numbers from the column names (or easier, remove the word "precipitation"):

   `gsub("precipitation", "", names(DT)[-1])`
3. Now find the sorting order of these numbers (after turning them into numeric values):

   `order(as.numeric(gsub("precipitation", "", names(DT)[-1])))`
4. Now we only have to add the first column to this order:

   `c(1, order(as.numeric(gsub("precipitation", "", names(DT)[-1]))) + 1)`
5. and pass the order to `setcolorder`:

   `setcolorder(DT, c(1, order(as.numeric(gsub("precipitation", "", names(DT)[-1]))) + 1))`